# How to forward mdns to android emulator

Tags: android, testing, udp, emulation, mdns

I need to run tests on Android Emulator. The app I need to test uses mdns to discover a device. Is there any way to connect the android emulator directly to my wifi network, or forward all mdns traffic to the android emulator?